# Many errors when there should be none in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am kinda new to android studio and kotlin and i am making a messaging app. Yesterday my code was working but today when i opened my project i got these errors that dont make any sense at all for me. I have been trying to fix these all day but no luck
if anyone could help it would be appreciate it.

this is my  MainActivity file

```
quxtar.com

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ClipData
import android.content.ContentProvider
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val emailui = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.email_register_scr)
        val passwordui = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.password_register_scr)
        val registerbtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.regidterbtn_register_scr)
        val loginbtn = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.login_register_scr)

        var email = emailui.text.toString()
        var password = passwordui.text.toString()

        val selectbtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.selectbutton_register)

        var selectPhotoURI: Uri? = null

        selectbtn.setOnClickListener(){


            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"

            println("image selecting")

            //compress
        }

        fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){

                //check selected image

                selectPhotoURI = data.data

                println("selectedphoto")
                println(selectPhotoURI)

                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectPhotoURI);

                val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)

                selectbtn.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)

            }

        }

    }

    registerbtn.setOnClickListener {
        performRegister()
    }

    loginbtn.setOnClickListener{
        println("Try to show log in activity")
        //launch login

        val intent = Intent(this, LogInActivity:: class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}

private fun performRegister(){

    val emailui = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.email_register_scr)
    val passwordui = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.password_register_scr)
    val email = emailui.text.toString()
    val password = passwordui.text.toString()

    if (email.isEmpty() or  password.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter a mail/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

    println("Mail: $email");
    println("Password: $password");

    //Fire base authentication to create user with mail and password
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                println(it.result?.user?.uid)

            }
            .addOnFailureListener() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create user: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                Log.d("Main", "failed to create user: ${it.message}}")

            }
}
```

and these are the errors

```
 e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (78, 5): Expecting member declaration

e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (78, 16): Expecting member declaration

e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (78, 17): Expecting member declaration

e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (78, 36): Conflicting overloads: public final fun <no name provided>(): Unit defined in quxtar.com.MainActivity, public final fun <no name provided>(): Unit defined in quxtar.com.MainActivity

e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (78, 36): Function declaration must have a name

e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (82, 32): Conflicting overloads: public final fun <no name provided>(): Unit defined in quxtar.com.MainActivity, public final fun <no name provided>(): Unit defined in quxtar.com.MainActivity

e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (82, 32): Function declaration must have a name

e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (95, 22): Unresolved reference: findViewById

e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (100, 24): 'this' is not defined in this context

e: C:\Users\hecto\AndroidStudioProjects\Hm\app\src\main\java\quxtar\com\MainActivity.kt: (117, 32): 'this' is not defined in this context
```

Comment: Well i was stupid and i dint have the brackets in the right place XD

Comment: `Yesterday my code was working but today when i opened my project i got these errors` that's never _really_ true

Answer (score 1):

You missed the second bracket.Below code should be out of the onCreate method.

```
fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){

            //check selected image

            selectPhotoURI = data.data

            println("selectedphoto")
            println(selectPhotoURI)

            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectPhotoURI);

            val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)

            selectbtn.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)

        }

    }
```

And this click listeners should be inside the onCreate.

```
 registerbtn.setOnClickListener {
    performRegister()
}

loginbtn.setOnClickListener{
    println("Try to show log in activity")
    //launch login

    val intent = Intent(this, LogInActivity:: class.java)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

And last of all you should place the missing bracket right after the "performRegister()" method.

I don't have enough reputation to comment that's why posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any name for the function defined on line no. 82 in your MainActivity.kt

Answer (score 0):

1. `onActivityResult` method are not recommended to place inside of `onCreate` method.
2. The declare of certain object is Wrong. Hence, this error appear (Expecting member declaration), (Unresolved reference: findViewById) and (Function declaration must have a name). Make sure do it the `OOP` way that the things you want to called be `public` or `global` instead of `private`or `protected`.
3. `'this' is not defined in this context` use Specific `this@MainActivity` instead.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This part of code is placed wrong:

```kotlin
registerbtn.setOnClickListener {
    performRegister()
}

loginbtn.setOnClickListener{
    println("Try to show log in activity")
    //launch login

    val intent = Intent(this, LogInActivity:: class.java)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

Correct version of your activity:

```kotlin
quxtar.com

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ClipData
import android.content.ContentProvider
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val emailui = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.email_register_scr)
        val passwordui = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.password_register_scr)
        val registerbtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.regidterbtn_register_scr)
        val loginbtn = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.login_register_scr)

        var email = emailui.text.toString()
        var password = passwordui.text.toString()

        val selectbtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.selectbutton_register)

        var selectPhotoURI: Uri? = null

        selectbtn.setOnClickListener(){


            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"

            println("image selecting")

            //compress
        }

        fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){

                //check selected image

                selectPhotoURI = data.data

                println("selectedphoto")
                println(selectPhotoURI)

                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectPhotoURI);

                val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)

                selectbtn.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)

            }

        }
        
        registerbtn.setOnClickListener {
            performRegister()
        }

        loginbtn.setOnClickListener{
            println("Try to show log in activity")
            //launch login

            val intent = Intent(this, LogInActivity:: class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

    }

}

private fun performRegister(){

    val emailui = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.email_register_scr)
    val passwordui = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.password_register_scr)
    val email = emailui.text.toString()
    val password = passwordui.text.toString()

    if (email.isEmpty() or  password.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter a mail/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

    println("Mail: $email");
    println("Password: $password");

    //Fire base authentication to create user with mail and password
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                println(it.result?.user?.uid)

            }
            .addOnFailureListener() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create user: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                Log.d("Main", "failed to create user: ${it.message}}")

            }
}
```

Comment: thanks i saw that right after posting the question silly me XD